# topコマンドをバッチモードで起動し、停止後、fgで再開することができない理由

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

何かしたいわけではないのですが、原因がわからないので、玄人の方にお聞きしたいです。

```
$ top -b
```

を Ctrl + Z で停止し、

```
fg %1(jobID)
```

で再開しようとすると、所望の動作をしません。
画面が崩れ気味ですし、何より Ctrl + C などの入力を受け付けなくなってしまいます。
理由がわかる方、教えてください。

Comment: top コマンド の man  ファイルの `-b` オプションの説明部分に、`In this mode, top will not accept input and runs until the iterations limit you've set with the -n command-line option` と書かれています。

Comment: @metropolis (SUSP後に fgすると)特殊制御文字 INTR QUIT SUSP が効かなくなる, という話かと。(そして多分 busyboxの topなら大丈夫)

Comment: @oriri おっしゃる通りでございます！

Answer (score 2):

top のソースファイルはたぶんここ https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/newlib/src/top/top.c

---

問題の動作の理由は, 本来の topコマンドのターミナル制御を batch-modeでも行ってしまっている ため

##### 本来の topコマンドの大まかな流れ

- [termios](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/LDP_man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) の `tcgetattr` にて現在のターミナル属性の取得 (`Tty_original`)。
  終了時に元に戻すなどで利用
- 端末 ECHO しないなど各種のターミナル属性の設定を行う (`Tty_raw`)。
  top 実行中に利用
- 各種のシグナルハンドラー登録。
  この中には <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> の `SIGTSTP`, 再開時の `SIGCONT` も含まれる
- シグナルハンドラー内では, `Tty_original` / `Tty_raw` を使い(タイミングに合わせ)ターミナル属性の設定を行う
- top コマンド終了時は元のターミナル属性に戻す

ここまでは問題はなく
問題の発生する原因は, batch-modeにあります

##### batch-mode

- ターミナル属性のセットアップ関数 `whack_terminal(void)` で, batch-mode時は `Tty_original` / `Tty_raw` をセットアップしていない。本来使わないはずなのでそれ自体は問題ない はず
- 各種のシグナルハンドラー登録は batch-modeの区別がなく, 登録される
- このため `SIGTSTP` からの再開で, `Tty_raw` の情報からターミナル属性が設定される
- `Tty_raw` 内容はセットアップされていない(全 NUL文字)ためキーが効かなくなる。
  そして LF (`'\n'`) の出力が 復帰無しになり, カーソル真下に移動のみ(のモード)になり画面が崩れる

---

問題の対処 … 以下が考えられるでしょう

- batch-modeでは `Tty_raw` を現在のターミナル属性でセットアップする
- もしくは, batch-modeではシグナルハンドラーを一部登録しないようにする
- (逃げ) batch-mode使わない, または <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> 使わない